# Using SVG as a flexible background with position: absolute;

Tags: html, css, svg

I'd like to be able to use inline SVGs as background images – without actually using them as CSS background images.

I need the ability to change the `fill` of the SVG, so with the help of some absolutely positioned elements I thought it would be possible to do it. But I'm not having much luck.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-bg">
    <svg><!-- SVG code --></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="block-text">
   <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this approach the SVG is placed behind the `<div class="block-text">` in an attempt to have it grow/shrink/respond to the content.

My current CSS:

```
.block {
  position: relative;
}

.block-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block-text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 10rem;
}

.block-bg svg {
  fill: grey;
}
```

Pretty simple stuff, but SVGs seem to be tricky to get to act right in certain circumstances.

Preserving the aspect ratio isn't needed, so the SVG shape can warp to whatever size the content forces it. I also need the SVG to be responsive – so when the viewport is wider or small the SVG scales accordingly. Is this possible?

Here's a Codepen with some example code: https://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/86f824a2d5a57279c19b33cf14d8904a

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Update your CSS so that `.block-bg svg` uses `width: 100%; height: 100%;` (along with your `fill`) and set the SVG's attribute `preserveAspectRatio` to `"none"`. Looks shiny on [this updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/chriskirknielsen/pen/YzywYQZ) — is that what you are after?

Comment: @chriskirknielsen Amazing - works exactly how I want it. Thank you. If you put your comment as the answer I can mark it as such.

Comment: Sure thing, glad to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SVG needs to fill out the space it's given with `width: 100%; height: 100%;`, and if you set the `preserveAspectRatio` to `"none"` on your SVG element, you will get the result you're after:

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
}

.block-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block-text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 10rem;
}

.block-bg svg {
  fill: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-bg">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1760 515" preserveAspectRatio="none"><!-- SVG code --></svg>
  </div>
  <div class="block-text">
   <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

With your CodePen SVG data, [here's an updated working demo](https://codepen.io/chriskirknielsen/pen/YzywYQZ).